# How to force strict evaluation of a sequence of ByteString

Tags: haskell, sequence, strict, bytestring

I have the following Haskell type definition:

```
import Data.Sequence(Seq, length)
import Data.ByteString.UTF8(ByteString)

type StringSeq = Seq ByteString
```

I have expressions of type `StringSeq` for which I would like to force strict evaluation with `deepseq`. So I need to define instances of `NFData`. I did the following:

```
import Control.DeepSeq(NFData, deepseq)

instance NFData ByteString

instance NFData a => NFData (Seq a) where
  rnf s = rnf (length s)
```

So I compute the length of a sequence to force evaluation of the sequence itself. This seems to work but is this the correct implementation? Are there better ones? Does computing the length of a sequence introduce too much overhead?

Comment: Computing the length of a `Seq` will do nothing useful, because a `Seq` is already spine-strict. It's certainly not a valid `NFData` instance, because it doesn't even try to force the contents of the `Seq`. Also, it's pretty unlikely that `NFData` is actually what you want; what is it you're really trying to do? `deepseq` is usually "too much, too late" for getting the right strictness behavior (and performance).

Comment: Apart from what shachaf said, there is already an `NFData` instance : `instance NFData a => NFData (Seq a) where rnf (Seq xs) = rnf xs`. (arrh, only in the `containers` coming with 7.6.1, not for the earlier versions)

Comment: But, all you have to do is `seq` the `ByteString`s before you put them in the `Seq`. Due to the spine strictness of `Seq`, that ensures complete evaluation.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: But the `Seq` is the result of a function: the function application returning the `Seq` must also be evaluated. I have to check if `seq` is enough here, maybe not?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a monad for strictness

```
data Strict a = Strict {fromStrict :: !a}
instance Monad Strict where
   return = Strict
   (Strict x) >>= f = f x
```

Okay, I don't think this actually obeys the monad laws, but it is close enough.  Using this you can define a function

```
srnf = Strict . rnf
```

such that

```
instance NFData a => NFData (Seq a) where
  rnf s = fromStrict $ (mapM srnf s) >> return ()
```

Untested, but should work (and it should work for all `Traversable` data structures).

Comment: I'm just curious, isn't `newtype Strict a = Strict { fromStrict :: a }` strict as well, with slightly better performance?

Comment: `newtype` isn't strict.  It just does not exist.  The point is that the pattern match in the definition of `>>=` forces evaluation when the identity monad does not.  You could use the newtype you defined, but you would have to say `Strict x >>= f = seq x $ f x`.

Answer (score 1):

Computing length is not enough, you need to compute the normal forms of the content of a sequence. I suggest you to use [seqFoldable](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parallel/3.2.0.3/doc/html/Control-Seq.html#g:5) from `Control.Seq` which allows you to force any foldable structure. Then you can call simply

```
mySeq `using` seqFoldable rdeepseq
```

or define

```
instance NFData a => NFData (Seq a) where
    rnf = seqFoldable rdeepseq
```