# How do I force evaluation of an IO action within `unsafePerformIO`?

Tags: haskell

```
import System.IO.Unsafe

main :: IO ()
main = do
  _ <- return $ unsafePerformIO $ do
    print "test2"
  print "test"
```

The above only outputs `test` (when run via `runghc`), I'm assuming due the lazy nature of Haskell that the first IO action does not actually get evaluated. How can I force it to evaluate and perform the action?

The above is for debugging purposes only.

Comment: For debugging purposes, I'd recommend using the [Debug.Trace](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html) module, which has an API that works around this issue.

Comment: Just use `$!` instead of `$` after `return`. No real need for the `_ <-` bit, by the way.

Comment: Delete the line `_ <- return $ unsafePerformIO $ do` and unindent the following line. But what's your *real* use-case where you actually need unsafePerformIO?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order for the IO side-effect to be executed, the "pure" value created by `unsafePerformIO` needs to be forced (i.e., evaluated at least to WHNF).

Unfortunately, your `main` function:

```
main = do
  _ <- return $ unsafePerformIO $ do
    print "test2"
  print "test"
```

desugars (as per the Haskell98 report) into:

```
main = let ok _ = do { print "test" }
           ok _ = fail "..."
       in return (unsafePerformIO (print "test2")) >>= ok
```

which is equivalent by the monad laws to:

```
main = let ok _ = do { print "test" }
           ok _ = fail "..."
       in ok (unsafePerformIO (print "test2"))
```

Sadly, the first part of the `let` binding:

```
let ok _ = do { print "test2" }
```

doesn't use -- and so doesn't force -- its argument when it's called, so the "pure" unsafe IO action is ignored.

Since pattern matching the "pure" value to its constructor (namely `()`) *would* force the value and so execute the unsafe action, if you write:

```
main = do
  () <- return $ unsafePerformIO $ do
    print "test2"
  print "test"
```

then that will work fine.

There are other ways to force the action.  You could pattern match explicitly:

```
main = do
  case unsafePerformIO (print "test2") of
    () -> return ()
  print "test"
```

or use `seq` either like so:

```
main = do
  unsafePerformIO (print "test2") `seq` print "test"
```

or like so:

```
main = do
  unsafePerformIO (print "test2") `seq` return ()
  print "test"
```

or use the strict evaluation operator:

```
main = do
  return $! unsafePerformIO (print "test2")
  print "test"
```

You can also use the `BangPatterns` extension as suggested by @Chris Stryczynski.

I'm not sure which is best, though I'd lean towards using the `($!)` operator as the most idiomatic.

As noted by @Carl, for debugging purposes, using `trace` from `Debug.Trace` is generally more sensible than calling `unsafePerformIO` directly, both because it's the standard way of printing debugging information from pure code and because the implementation is a little more thoughtful than a simple `unsafePerformIO . putStrLn`.  However, it potentially exhibits the same issue:

```
import Debug.Trace
main = do
  return $ trace "test2" ()  -- won't actually print anything
  print "test"
```

Instead, you need to force it's value, perhaps by using one of the methods above:

```
import Debug.Trace
main = do
  return $! trace "test2" ()  -- with ($!) this works
  print "test"
```

When @Carl says that `trace` has an API that works around this issue, he means that you normally use trace in a situation like:

```
let value_i_actually_use = trace "my message" value_of_the_trace_expression
```

When you actually *use* (evaluate) the value of the `trace` expression, then the message will be displayed.

and then

Comment: To trace in a monad I usually trace the action rather than the value: `trace "test2" $ return ()`rather than `return $! trace "test2" ()` -- it's just clearer to me that it will definitely be evaluated when sequenced.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially there are some limitations with the below (mentioned in the comments of the referenced answer).

More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14163739/1663462

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
import System.IO.Unsafe

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let !_ = unsafePerformIO $ do
         print "test2"
  print "test"
```