# How can I force debug trace statements to evaluate in order?

Tags: debugging, haskell, io, lazy-evaluation, trace

```
import Debug.Trace

main  :: IO ()
main = do
  let b = (fff 2 10)
  print b
  let c = (fff 3 10)
  print c
  print "---"


ff :: (->) Int Int
ff = do
  x <- traceShow "x is: " . traceShowId
  pure $ (x)

fff :: Int -> Int -> Int
fff = do
  (-) . ff
```

The trace functions seem to be lazily evaluated or something which means the output can vary from:

```
"x is: "
2
-8
"x is: "
-7
3
"---"
```

And in another run:

```
"x is: "
2
"x is: "
3
-8
-7
"---"
```

I've tried the suggestions from here: [How do I force evaluation of an IO action within `unsafePerformIO`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48977455/how-do-i-force-evaluation-of-an-io-action-within-unsafeperformio) (BangPatterns Pragma + `$!`) as well as adding the `Strict` and `StrictData` pragmas, however I still get the inconsistent behavior.

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE Strict #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StrictData #-}

import Debug.Trace

main  :: IO ()
main = do
  let !b = (fff 2 10)
  print b
  let !c = (fff 3 10)
  print c
  print "---"

ff :: (->) Int Int
ff = do
  x <- id $! (traceShow "x is: " . traceShowId)
  pure $ (x)

fff :: Int -> Int -> Int
fff = do
  (-) . ff
```

---

I've also tried using `unsafePerformIo` but this has similar behavior:

```
hmm :: a -> a
hmm x = unsafePerformIO $! do
  pure x

ff :: Int -> Int
ff z = do
  hmm (trace "x is: " . traceShowId) $ z
```

---

Is there a solution without having to have knowledge about strictness / Haskell's evaluation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Debug.Trace` functions print to `stderr` so interleaving is to be expected.

At the very least, you could put `x` and the string before it together to distinguish it from other `print` output.

```
ff :: Int -> Int
ff x = trace ("x is: " ++ show x) x
```

You can also use `unsafePerformIO` to redefine trace functions that print to `stdout` to enforce some ordering.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're dealing with buffering issues. You can use `hFlush` or just set the buffering:

```
hSetBuffering stderr NoBuffering
hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - does not seem to work though.

Answer (score 1):

```
myTrace :: Show a => a -> a
myTrace x = unsafePerformIO $ do
  print x
  pure x
```

The above seems to work well. Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/6863749/li-yao-xia